# issues trying to make rows in c program

Tags: c, loops, rows, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int prime(int limit,int col);
int main(){        
    int limit,col,count,i;

    printf("Table of Primes\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("Upper limit: ");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    getchar();
    printf("# of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&col);

    count=prime( limit,col);

    return 0;
}

int prime(int limit,int col){
    int i,j,w;

    for(w=0;w<col;w++){     
        for(i=2;i<=limit;i++){    
            for(j=2;j<=i;j++){    
                if(i%j==0){    
                    break;    
                }    
            }               
            if(i==j){    
                printf("%d ",i);        
            }    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }       
}
```

The code above is to find the amount of prime numbers between 2 and the user input numbers.
I have that working fine, but my issue is getting the Code to be put into columns (defined by # of columns)
I talked this over with my teacher and she said that I do not have to use a 2D array to accomplish this.
Can anyone please help me out?

Also the output is spouse to look like this:

```
 Table of Primes
 ===============
 Upper limit:  175
 # of columns: 5
  2      3      5      7     11
 13     17     19     23     29
 31     37     41     43     47
 53     59     61     67     71
 73     79     83     89     97
101    103    107    109    113
127    131    137    139    149
151    157    163    167    173
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make separate functions for finding primes and displaying primes, so you will have more control on displaying those primes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> // sqrt

int is_prime (int x);
void prime(int limit, int col);

int main ()
{
    int limit, col;

    printf("Table of Primes\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("Upper limit: ");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    getchar();
    printf("# of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&col);

    prime(limit, col);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}


int is_prime (int num)
{
    int flag;
    int i;
    double p;

    p = sqrt(num);
    flag = 1;

    if (num == 1)
        return 0;

    if (num == 2)
        return flag;

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
        return 0;

    for (i = 3; i <= p; i += 2)
    {
        if ((num % i) == 0)
        {
            flag = false;
            return flag;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}


void prime (int limit, int column)
{
    int i, j, cnt;;

    cnt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            printf("%4d ", i);
            cnt++;
            if ((cnt % column) == 0) {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can change is_prime to your own function.

Comment: Thank you. This was another idea I had but since the workshop suggested I only use one function including the main, So i was worried that it would be an issue with grading. Regardless, its a big help. ill be sure to use this for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test the number of columns and print a `newline`. The function `prime()` also lacked a return value so I return `w` as the number of primes found. This is just a slight tweak to your `prime()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int prime(int limit, int col) {
int i, j, w = 0;
    for (i=2; i<=limit; i++) {
        for (j=2; j<=i; j++) {
            if (i%j == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i==j) {
            if (w++ % col == 0)               // test number of columns
                printf("\n");
            printf("%7d", i);                // specify field width
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return w;
}

int main(void) {
    prime (173, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
  2      3      5      7     11
 13     17     19     23     29
 31     37     41     43     47
 53     59     61     67     71
 73     79     83     89     97
101    103    107    109    113
127    131    137    139    149
151    157    163    167    173
```

I leave you to add the frills.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was extremely helpful! I had a feeling it had a little to do with my return value of the function prime

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a variable to count how many numbers have been printed, then `count % col` will be zero every time `count` is a multiple of col, so this would work

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prime(int limit, int col);
int readint(const char *const message);

int main()
{
    int limit,col;

    printf("Table of Primes\n");
    printf("===============\n");

    limit = readint("Upper limit");
    col   = readint("# of columns");

    prime(limit, col);

    return 0;
}

int readint(const char *const message)
{
    int value;

    printf("%s> ", message);
    while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
    {
        int chr;

        printf("\tinvalid input\n");
        printf("%s> ", message);
        do {
            chr = getchar();
        } while ((chr != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
    }
    return value;
}

void prime(int limit, int col)
{
    int i, j;
    int count;

    count = 0;
    for (i = 2 ; i <= limit ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2 ; j <= i ; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (i == j)
        {
            count += 1;

            printf("%5d", i);
            if ((count != 0) && (count % col == 0))
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your code does not handle invalid input, I added that in this code, many people erroneously ignore `scanf()`'s return value, which is there for a reason.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to C programming. Your edit helped further understand invalid input. I'm actually just about to learn about pointers this week in school, this will definitely help!